# how can I use multiple attributes in params condition in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I want to use filter in CgridView in admin.php.My filter code is

```
$kosul=array(
 'condition'=>"role=:role",
 'params'=>array(':role'=>'Admin' OR ':role'=>'SuperAdmin'),
);
```

and I want to use the code in CgridView at following line

```
'dataProvider'=>$model->search($kosul),
```

But "OR" code didn't run.

```
 'params'=>array(':role'=>'Admin' OR ':role'=>'SuperAdmin'),
```

How can I use "OR" in params.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code:

```
$kosul=array(
'condition'=>"role ='Admin' OR role='SuperAdmin'",

);
```